# Where is the best place to put const in C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style, constants

I have done C# and C, but still, when I come to this C++ project, I am a little stucked for this little code style problem.

I have a couple of const variables(might be strings or numbers) in a C++ program, and I want to gather them in one place and access them from other classes.

For example, in C# and java, we can have a resource file or a config file to store all those data, or maybe just a singleton or static class.

But what is the best way I should do it with C++? should I put the const variables in a header file or make a class like JAVA?

Comment: Do you want access at compile time or run time? That is, do want them compiled right into the code, or do you want a file full of them that is read when the code runs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO this is one of the shortcoming of C# and Java - everything has to be inside a class.

In C++ you have <del>two</del> three options:

- inside a class
- in a namespace
- free variables (don't)

If your constants are logically related to a class, put them in the class. Otherwise, use a `namespace`.

Comment: It seems OP is considering static constants; these cannot not be class members unless of integral type. So the namespace solution appears the most suitable.

Comment: @Walter any static class members can be const. Integrals can be initialized inside the class definition, but that's the only restriction.